# Compiler error generated in unix terminal but not in visual studio 2013 when opening filestream

Tags: c++, linux, filestream

My code looks like this

```
ifstream myfile;
string fileName;
cin >> filename;
myfile.open(fileName);
```

I'm getting a rather lengthy error message and can't figure out how to pipe it to a file(I tried a couple things and think I might not have permissions, since I'm on my school's remote terminal), so I took a screenshot.

[image]

Sorry if that's taboo, but it was the quickest thing I could think of. The line it is referencing(main.cpp 22) is the line

```
myfile.open(fileName);
```

Again, compiles and runs perfectly in Visual Studio 2013, but not in this linux shell. Honestly, if anyone could help me understand the error message that would be a start.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Screeen shots are ugly but not taboo. But your's unreadable.

Comment: Oh, I made the mistake of not previewing it before posting. I assumed the link would be posted and not the screenshot itself.

Comment: Hint: reduce the xterm size before taking the shot.

Comment: My guess is that you are not including some header file that you are relying on. This "works" on some systems but not on others because some of the system headers sometimes include things that are "useful", and on other systems it doesn't in the same way. Always include ALL headers that YOUR code uses.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the compiler flag `-std=c++11`. The following program compiles and builds fine on my machine using:

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++11    test-484.cc   -o test-484
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   ifstream myfile;
   string fileName;
   cin >> fileName;
   myfile.open(fileName);
   return 0;
}
```

BTW, in your posted code, you have

```
   string filename;
              ^^ lower case n not upper case N
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work. My only concern is whether my professor will compile it with that flag or not.

Comment: If you don't want to use C++11, then fix your code (using `myfile.open(filename.c_str());` should make it compatible with older versions of C++)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using C++11, you can also do the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main () {
std::ifstream myfile;
std::string fileName;
std::cin >> fileName;
myfile.open(fileName.c_str());
}
```

But accessing the C string directly this way is not a good thing, if possible, follow R Sahu's suggestion to use C++11.

Comment: Thanks, I will make this change if my professor doesn't compile it using the flag R Sahu suggested